# how to update state with arrays in ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-reducers

I am trying to migrate my application to use ngrx. One of the first features is loading my actual content and displaying it, but I have some issues.

I defined this in my reducer:

```
export const collectionFeatureKey = 'colecciones';

export interface CollectionsState {
  lista_creadas: Array<Collection>;
  lista_asignadas: Array<Collection>;
  lista_grupos: Array<Collection>;
}

export const initialState: CollectionsState = {
  lista_creadas: [],
  lista_asignadas : [],
  lista_grupos: []
};
```

I prepared and effect that get the information from API. IT work fine. But I don't know how to asign the value of the three arrays to the state, Actually i'm doing this:

```
const collectionsReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(CollectionActions.loadCollections, state => state),
    on(CollectionActions.loadCollectionsSucess,
      (state, { colecciones }) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          colecciones
        };
      }
    ),
    on(CollectionActions.loadCollectionsError, state => state),
/*...*/
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe  `{ ...state, ...colecciones }` would work?  `{ colecciones }` is the same as `{ colecciones: colecciones }`.

Comment: Yes, like a charm. But why?

Comment: Because `colecciones` is an object and the state is only interested in this object's properties(`lista_creadas`, `lista_asignadas` etc..). In order to use what's inside `colecciones` object you can apply the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colecciones is an object, and you will have to assign each array to the state's array:

```
   on(CollectionActions.loadCollectionsSucess,
      (state, { colecciones }) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          lista_creadas: colecciones.lista_creadas
          lista_asignadas: colecciones.lista_asignadas
          lista_grupos: colecciones.lista_grupos
        };
      }
    ),
```

There's a shortcut for this with the spread operator:

```
   on(CollectionActions.loadCollectionsSucess,
      (state, { colecciones }) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          ...colecciones
        };
      }
    ),
```

But since your action contains the payload which is equivalent to the next state you can also do:

```
  on(CollectionActions.loadCollectionsSucess,
      (state, { colecciones }) => {
        return colecciones
      }
    ),
```